# AssertSame -Junit

Tags: java, junit, юнит-тесты

У меня есть арр:

```
public class App {

    public static String s = "Hello Alex!";
    public static Integer iw = 1234567890;
    public static Boolean tw = true;
    public static Boolean fw = false;

    public static void main( String[] args ) { 
        System.out.println( "Thanks!" );
    }
}
```

Когда я пишу юнит-тест с использованием `assertSame` на `Int`:

```
@Test
public void Test04_AssertSame_Pos(){
    assertSame("Integer not the same", 1234567890, App.iw);
    System.out.println("Test04_AssertSame_Pos");
}
```

он Failed с сообщением

> Test04_AssertSame_Pos(core.AppTest): Integer not the same expected same:<1234567890> was not:<1234567890>

Это как? Где моя ошибка? Пытаясь разобраться обнаружено, что работает только в диапазоне `(127) - (-128)`, то есть не видит `Int`, а воспринимает только `byte`. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с *autoboxing*-ом значения примитивного типа `int` в ссылочный тип `Integer`.

`assertSame` сравнивает два значения через оператор `==`. В вашем случае сравнивается экземпляр класса `Integer` со значением `1234567890`, лежащий в поле `iw`, со значением `1234567890` типа `int`, которое передано явно, но неявно оборачивается в новый экземпляр `Integer` (по сути происходит `new Integer(1234567890)`).

Оператор `==` для ссылочных типов выполняет сравнение адресов. Т.к. экземпляры разные, то и адреса разные. Равенство не выполняется.

В диапазоне `(127) - (-128)` сравнение срабатывает, так как для класса `Integer` существует кэш значений, который как раз содержит `Integer`-ы в упомянутом диапазоне (см. класс `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache`), и при *autoboxing*-е значения берутся из кэша.

---

TL;DR: используйте `assertEquals`, он сравнивает по значению.